# specifying multiple URLs with cURL/PHP using square brackets

Tags: php, url, curl

I have a large array of URLS similar to this:

```
 $nodes = array(
    'http://www.example.com/product.php?page=1&sortOn=sellprice',
    'http://www.example.com/product.php?page=2&sortOn=sellprice',
    'http://www.example.com/product.php?page=3&sortOn=sellprice'
);
```

The `cURL` manual states here (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) that i can use square brackets '[]' to specify multiple urls.  Used in the above example this would be similar to this:

```
'http://www.example.com/product.php?page=[1-3]&sortOn=sellprice'
```

So far i have been unable to reference this correctly.  This is the complete code segment I'm currently trying to utilize this with:

```
$nodes = array(
    'http://www.example.com/product.php?page=1&sortOn=sellprice',
    'http://www.example.com/product.php?page=2&sortOn=sellprice',
    'http://www.example.com/product.php?page=3&sortOn=sellprice' 
);

$node_count = count($nodes);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $url =$nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);

echo "results: ";
for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
    echo( $i . "\n" . $results . "\n");
echo 'done';
```

I can't seem to find any more documentation on this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs you linked are the manpage for the cURL command line binary and do *not* apply to [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), which is what PHP uses. If you want to retrieve multiple URLs simultaneously in PHP, the correct way to do it is with the `curl_multi_*` functions, as you seem to be aware based on the code sample you show.

Comment: Thank you, I will continue to research the curl_multi_* functions in order to refine my code.